# Partial String Matching in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a string column with several different 4 character that can be separated by `|` or `&`, but not always. I am trying to map a dictionary to each discrete 4 character item but am running into issues. pandas ver 23.4

The basic code I am trying to use:

`df = df.replace(dict, regex=True)`

or if trying to select a specific col:

`df['Col'] = df['Col'].replace(dict, regex=True)`

Both raise the following error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more that one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

The values of the dictionary are type `list`. Is this something that would be an issue with performing the `.replace`?

**Update With Sample df and dict**

```
 ID       Code
ABCD      00FQ
JKFA    8LK9|4F5H
QWST    2RLA|R1T5&8LK9


dict={'00FQ':['A','B'], '8LK9':['X'], '4F5H':['U','Z'], '2RLA':['H','K'], 'R1T5':['B','G'] }
```

The dict will have more elements in it than in the dataframe.

**Update with expected output**

```
 ID       Code           Logic
ABCD      00FQ          ['A','B']
JKFA    8LK9|4F5H       ['X'] | ['U','Z']
QWST    2RLA|R1T5&8LK9  ['H','K'] | ['B','G'] & ['X']
```

The overall goal is to perform this replace on **two** dataframes, and then compare the `ID's` on both sides for equivalence.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your df?

Comment: @YaakovBressler updated

Comment: The values of the dict here seems to be string... if they are indeed list, you'll get the above error, but if they are strings, I think you'll not get the error.

Comment: @najeem edited to reflect that they are indeed of type `list` sry

Comment: The error is because it's a list. are you trying to replace the str with list?

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: Updated with sample output. I am trying to replace the strings with list yes

Answer (score 0):

The regex defined in your dict might be matching with more than one rows of the dataframe, and python is confused about which replacement value to take from the dict.

And, when a numpy array is checked for its boolean value, this Error is forced to save users from guessing.
Would you consider an array of elements to be True if

- Any of its element is True or
- All of its elements are True
  or
- Something else.

Thus it throws this error to allow the programmer to explicitly mention it.

Go [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) for more clarification.

Comment: There will absolutely be more than one match in the column

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a function which will allow you to parse relevant values from your strings:**

```
def string_to_list(string):
    """
    parses a parent string for 4 character children strings
    returns a list of children strings
    """
    # instantiate values
    child = ''
    children = []

    if len(string)<4:
        return None

    for n in string:
        # skip if not wanted
        if n in ['|','&']:
            continue

        child+=n
        if len(child)==4:
            children.append(child)
            child = ''

    # finished
    return children
```

**Apply it to extract a list of values as follows:**

```
df['Code_List'] = df['Code'].apply(string_to_list)
```

**Map to relevant `logic` values:**

```
# Instantiate the dictionary of logic rules
logic_dict = {'00FQ':['A','B'], '8LK9':['X'], '4F5H':['U','Z'], '2RLA':['H','K'], 'R1T5':['B','G'] }

# Map the logic rules
df['Logic_List'] = df['Code_List'].apply(lambda arr: [logic_dict[x] for x in arr])

# Final output
    ID      Code            Code_List           Logic_List
0   ABCD    00FQ            [00FQ]              [[A, B]]
1   JKFA    8LK9|4F5H       [8LK9, 4F5H]        [[X], [U, Z]]
2   QWST    2RLA|R1T5&8LK9  [2RLA, R1T5, 8LK9]  [[H, K], [B, G], [X]]
```

Comment: I must update the question. There will be more elements in the dictionary than in the `Code` col of the dataframe. The logic of the expression must remain intact.

Comment: This solution can be applied to any column containing 4 string substrings.

Comment: Did you consider modifying and applying to your situation @MaxB ?

Comment: I believe this solution will not work because the boolean logic associated with the `Code` expression must remain intact

Comment: Perhaps modify your Q to include *your desired output* @MaxB

Comment: @MaxB there is enough information in this response for it to satisfy your Q, though I acknowledge that it does not solve your desired output to perfection. Do keep in mind that SO is not a code review or homework guide site. Be mindful of the work you're asking of people – and the work they've provided.

Comment: Your answer does not maintain the logic, I do not believe that it satisfies the question.